# Probability: More yellow apples than red apples

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

There is a bowl with 4 red and 5 yellow apples on a table. A sample of three apples is drawn from the bowl.

Find the probability that there are more yellow apples than red apples.

I know this problem is supposed to use combinations and permutations, but whenever I look at it I draw a blank.

Comment: Just split it into P(3Y,0R) + P(2Y,1R).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** There are more yellow apples than red apples if you either pick two yellow apples and one red apple, or three yellow apples and no red apples.  What is the probability of doing each of those things?  Add them up and you'll get your answer.